# Operations on non atomic primitive variables

Tags: java

Reads and writes on long and double are not atomic. What's the worst that can happen if multiple threads access them simultaneously? Garbage values, or something more sinister?

Comment: What's worse that not being able to trust the values you're reading? I suppose some hardware system could be wired up to trap (at least sometimes) on such an access, causing your program to crash.  But arguably that's not worse than reading garbage, because at least you'd be informed that there was a problem.

Comment: Unintentional divide-by-zero or ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what operations. If you're only reading them, then nothing bad would happen. Mixing reads/writes without synchronization of some sort, though, is almost always asking for trouble.

Comment: any trouble besides garbage values?

Comment: What other kinds of trouble are you expecting? The main issue in my experience is that no synchronization tends to lead to unexpected values. If there are other kinds of concurrency issues that can happen when dealing with primitives I'm not aware of them...

Answer (score 1):

You could get garbage values which could be quite sinister depending on how you use the unreliable variables.